# CSS: making the select field width and height same as all other input fields?

Tags: css

I grabbed some CSS from the bootstrap css file to use in my code.

Everything works fine but the only issue that I have is the fact that the `<select></select>` field width and height is not same as other inputs on my page.

```css
.newins {
  background-color: #d9dada !important;
  width: 88% !important;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: 'VAG Rundschrift D';
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #747272;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s
}

.form-control:focus {
  /*border-color:#66afe9;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6)*/
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999
}

.form-control::-ms-expand {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0
}

.form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 1
}

.form-control[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  cursor: not-allowed
}

textarea.form-control {
  height: auto
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  input[type=date].form-control,
  input[type=time].form-control,
  input[type=datetime-local].form-control,
  input[type=month].form-control {
    line-height: 34px
  }
  .input-group-sm input[type=date],
  .input-group-sm input[type=time],
  .input-group-sm input[type=datetime-local],
  .input-group-sm input[type=month],
  input[type=date].input-sm,
  input[type=time].input-sm,
  input[type=datetime-local].input-sm,
  input[type=month].input-sm {
    line-height: 30px
  }
  .input-group-lg input[type=date],
  .input-group-lg input[type=time],
  .input-group-lg input[type=datetime-local],
  .input-group-lg input[type=month],
  input[type=date].input-lg,
  input[type=time].input-lg,
  input[type=datetime-local].input-lg,
  input[type=month].input-lg {
    line-height: 46px
  }
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.checkbox,
.radio {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.checkbox label,
.radio label {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox],
.checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox],
.radio input[type=radio],
.radio-inline input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px\9;
  margin-left: -20px
}

.checkbox+.checkbox,
.radio+.radio {
  margin-top: -5px
}

.checkbox-inline,
.radio-inline {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer
}

.checkbox-inline+.checkbox-inline,
.radio-inline+.radio-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 10px
}

fieldset[disabled] input[type=checkbox],
fieldset[disabled] input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox].disabled,
input[type=checkbox][disabled],
input[type=radio].disabled,
input[type=radio][disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.checkbox-inline.disabled,
.radio-inline.disabled,
fieldset[disabled] .checkbox-inline,
fieldset[disabled] .radio-inline {
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.checkbox.disabled label,
.radio.disabled label,
fieldset[disabled] .checkbox label,
fieldset[disabled] .radio label {
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.form-control-static {
  min-height: 34px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.form-control-static.input-lg,
.form-control-static.input-sm {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0
}

.input-sm {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px
}

select.input-sm {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px
}

select[multiple].input-sm,
textarea.input-sm {
  height: auto
}

.form-group-sm .form-control {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px
}

.form-group-sm select.form-control {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px
}

.form-group-sm select[multiple].form-control,
.form-group-sm textarea.form-control {
  height: auto
}

.form-group-sm .form-control-static {
  height: 30px;
  min-height: 32px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5
}

.input-lg {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px
}

select.input-lg {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px
}

select[multiple].input-lg,
textarea.input-lg {
  height: auto
}

.form-group-lg .form-control {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px
}

.form-group-lg select.form-control {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px
}

.form-group-lg select[multiple].form-control,
.form-group-lg textarea.form-control {
  height: auto
}

.form-group-lg .form-control-static {
  height: 46px;
  min-height: 38px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333
}

.has-feedback {
  position: relative
}

.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 42.5px
}

.form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none
}

.form-group-lg .form-control+.form-control-feedback,
.input-group-lg+.form-control-feedback,
.input-lg+.form-control-feedback {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px
}

.form-group-sm .form-control+.form-control-feedback,
.input-group-sm+.form-control-feedback,
.input-sm+.form-control-feedback {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px
}

.has-success .checkbox,
.has-success .checkbox-inline,
.has-success .control-label,
.has-success .help-block,
.has-success .radio,
.has-success .radio-inline,
.has-success.checkbox label,
.has-success.checkbox-inline label,
.has-success.radio label,
.has-success.radio-inline label {
  color: #3c763d
}

.has-success .form-control {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)
}

.has-success .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #2b542c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #67b168
}

.has-success .input-group-addon {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #3c763d
}

.has-success .form-control-feedback {
  color: #3c763d
}

.has-warning .checkbox,
.has-warning .checkbox-inline,
.has-warning .control-label,
.has-warning .help-block,
.has-warning .radio,
.has-warning .radio-inline,
.has-warning.checkbox label,
.has-warning.checkbox-inline label,
.has-warning.radio label,
.has-warning.radio-inline label {
  color: #8a6d3b
}

.has-warning .form-control {
  border-color: #8a6d3b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)
}

.has-warning .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66512c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b
}

.has-warning .input-group-addon {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #8a6d3b
}

.has-warning .form-control-feedback {
  color: #8a6d3b
}

.has-error .checkbox,
.has-error .checkbox-inline,
.has-error .control-label,
.has-error .help-block,
.has-error .radio,
.has-error .radio-inline,
.has-error.checkbox label,
.has-error.checkbox-inline label,
.has-error.radio label,
.has-error.radio-inline label {
  color: #a94442
}

.has-error .form-control {
  border-color: #a94442;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)
}

.has-error .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #843534;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #ce8483
}

.has-error .input-group-addon {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #a94442
}

.has-error .form-control-feedback {
  color: #a94442
}

.has-feedback label~.form-control-feedback {
  top: 25px
}

.has-feedback label.sr-only~.form-control-feedback {
  top: 0
}

.help-block {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #737373
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  .form-inline .form-control-static {
    display: inline-block
  }
  .form-inline .input-group {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  .form-inline .input-group .form-control,
  .form-inline .input-group .input-group-addon,
  .form-inline .input-group .input-group-btn {
    width: auto
  }
  .form-inline .input-group>.form-control {
    width: 100%
  }
  .form-inline .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  .form-inline .checkbox,
  .form-inline .radio {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle
  }
  .form-inline .checkbox label,
  .form-inline .radio label {
    padding-left: 0
  }
  .form-inline .checkbox input[type=checkbox],
  .form-inline .radio input[type=radio] {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0
  }
}

.form-horizontal .checkbox,
.form-horizontal .checkbox-inline,
.form-horizontal .radio,
.form-horizontal .radio-inline {
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.form-horizontal .checkbox,
.form-horizontal .radio {
  min-height: 27px
}

.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: right
  }
}

.form-horizontal .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  right: 15px
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control newins" id="coll" placeholder="Collection">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select id="len" class="form-control newins">
    <option value="">Length</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
.newins{
background-color:#d9dada !important;
width:88% !important;
padding:12px;
font-family: 'VAG Rundschrift D';
border:none;
border-radius:5px;
margin-top:7px;
font-size:1.1em;
color:#747272;
font-size:20px !important;

}
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Comment: Update `.form-control` with `height: 50px; padding: 0px 12px;` instead of the current values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is with padding when you are removing the padding width of inputs are same.Otherwise you can use [box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/).When use this padding will be subtracted from the width.

```css
input{
  height:44px;
}
select{
  height:34px;
}
.newins{
    background-color:#d9dada !important;
    width:88% ;
    padding:12px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    font-family: 'VAG Rundschrift D';
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:7px;
    font-size:1.1em;
    color:#747272;
    font-size:20px !important;
    }

.form-control{display:block;width:100%;padding:6px 12px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#555;background-color:#fff;background-image:none;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);-webkit-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;-o-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s}.form-control:focus{/*border-color:#66afe9;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6)*/}.form-control::-moz-placeholder{color:#999;opacity:1}.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#999}.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#999}.form-control::-ms-expand{background-color:transparent;border:0}.form-control[disabled],.form-control[readonly],fieldset[disabled] .form-control{background-color:#eee;opacity:1}.form-control[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .form-control{cursor:not-allowed}textarea.form-control{height:auto}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:none}@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){input[type=date].form-control,input[type=time].form-control,input[type=datetime-local].form-control,input[type=month].form-control{line-height:34px}.input-group-sm input[type=date],.input-group-sm input[type=time],.input-group-sm input[type=datetime-local],.input-group-sm input[type=month],input[type=date].input-sm,input[type=time].input-sm,input[type=datetime-local].input-sm,input[type=month].input-sm{line-height:30px}.input-group-lg input[type=date],.input-group-lg input[type=time],.input-group-lg input[type=datetime-local],.input-group-lg input[type=month],input[type=date].input-lg,input[type=time].input-lg,input[type=datetime-local].input-lg,input[type=month].input-lg{line-height:46px}}.form-group{margin-bottom:15px}.checkbox,.radio{position:relative;display:block;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px}.checkbox label,.radio label{min-height:20px;padding-left:20px;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:400;cursor:pointer}.checkbox input[type=checkbox],.checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox],.radio input[type=radio],.radio-inline input[type=radio]{position:absolute;margin-top:4px\9;margin-left:-20px}.checkbox+.checkbox,.radio+.radio{margin-top:-5px}.checkbox-inline,.radio-inline{position:relative;display:inline-block;padding-left:20px;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:400;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer}.checkbox-inline+.checkbox-inline,.radio-inline+.radio-inline{margin-top:0;margin-left:10px}fieldset[disabled] input[type=checkbox],fieldset[disabled] input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox].disabled,input[type=checkbox][disabled],input[type=radio].disabled,input[type=radio][disabled]{cursor:not-allowed}.checkbox-inline.disabled,.radio-inline.disabled,fieldset[disabled] .checkbox-inline,fieldset[disabled] .radio-inline{cursor:not-allowed}.checkbox.disabled label,.radio.disabled label,fieldset[disabled] .checkbox label,fieldset[disabled] .radio label{cursor:not-allowed}.form-control-static{min-height:34px;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:7px;margin-bottom:0}.form-control-static.input-lg,.form-control-static.input-sm{padding-right:0;padding-left:0}.input-sm{height:30px;padding:5px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5;border-radius:3px}select.input-sm{height:30px;line-height:30px}select[multiple].input-sm,textarea.input-sm{height:auto}.form-group-sm .form-control{height:30px;padding:5px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5;border-radius:3px}.form-group-sm select.form-control{height:30px;line-height:30px}.form-group-sm select[multiple].form-control,.form-group-sm textarea.form-control{height:auto}.form-group-sm .form-control-static{height:30px;min-height:32px;padding:6px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5}.input-lg{height:46px;padding:10px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.3333333;border-radius:6px}select.input-lg{height:46px;line-height:46px}select[multiple].input-lg,textarea.input-lg{height:auto}.form-group-lg .form-control{height:46px;padding:10px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.3333333;border-radius:6px}.form-group-lg select.form-control{height:46px;line-height:46px}.form-group-lg select[multiple].form-control,.form-group-lg textarea.form-control{height:auto}.form-group-lg .form-control-static{height:46px;min-height:38px;padding:11px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.3333333}.has-feedback{position:relative}.has-feedback .form-control{padding-right:42.5px}.form-control-feedback{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:2;display:block;width:34px;height:34px;line-height:34px;text-align:center;pointer-events:none}.form-group-lg .form-control+.form-control-feedback,.input-group-lg+.form-control-feedback,.input-lg+.form-control-feedback{width:46px;height:46px;line-height:46px}.form-group-sm .form-control+.form-control-feedback,.input-group-sm+.form-control-feedback,.input-sm+.form-control-feedback{width:30px;height:30px;line-height:30px}.has-success .checkbox,.has-success .checkbox-inline,.has-success .control-label,.has-success .help-block,.has-success .radio,.has-success .radio-inline,.has-success.checkbox label,.has-success.checkbox-inline label,.has-success.radio label,.has-success.radio-inline label{color:#3c763d}.has-success .form-control{border-color:#3c763d;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075)}.has-success .form-control:focus{border-color:#2b542c;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #67b168;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #67b168}.has-success .input-group-addon{color:#3c763d;background-color:#dff0d8;border-color:#3c763d}.has-success .form-control-feedback{color:#3c763d}.has-warning .checkbox,.has-warning .checkbox-inline,.has-warning .control-label,.has-warning .help-block,.has-warning .radio,.has-warning .radio-inline,.has-warning.checkbox label,.has-warning.checkbox-inline label,.has-warning.radio label,.has-warning.radio-inline label{color:#8a6d3b}.has-warning .form-control{border-color:#8a6d3b;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075)}.has-warning .form-control:focus{border-color:#66512c;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #c0a16b;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #c0a16b}.has-warning .input-group-addon{color:#8a6d3b;background-color:#fcf8e3;border-color:#8a6d3b}.has-warning .form-control-feedback{color:#8a6d3b}.has-error .checkbox,.has-error .checkbox-inline,.has-error .control-label,.has-error .help-block,.has-error .radio,.has-error .radio-inline,.has-error.checkbox label,.has-error.checkbox-inline label,.has-error.radio label,.has-error.radio-inline label{color:#a94442}.has-error .form-control{border-color:#a94442;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075)}.has-error .form-control:focus{border-color:#843534;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483}.has-error .input-group-addon{color:#a94442;background-color:#f2dede;border-color:#a94442}.has-error .form-control-feedback{color:#a94442}.has-feedback label~.form-control-feedback{top:25px}.has-feedback label.sr-only~.form-control-feedback{top:0}.help-block{display:block;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px;color:#737373}@media (min-width:768px){.form-inline .form-group{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}.form-inline .form-control{display:inline-block;width:auto;vertical-align:middle}.form-inline .form-control-static{display:inline-block}.form-inline .input-group{display:inline-table;vertical-align:middle}.form-inline .input-group .form-control,.form-inline .input-group .input-group-addon,.form-inline .input-group .input-group-btn{width:auto}.form-inline .input-group>.form-control{width:100%}.form-inline .control-label{margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}.form-inline .checkbox,.form-inline .radio{display:inline-block;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}.form-inline .checkbox label,.form-inline .radio label{padding-left:0}.form-inline .checkbox input[type=checkbox],.form-inline .radio input[type=radio]{position:relative;margin-left:0}.form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback{top:0}}.form-horizontal .checkbox,.form-horizontal .checkbox-inline,.form-horizontal .radio,.form-horizontal .radio-inline{padding-top:7px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}.form-horizontal .checkbox,.form-horizontal .radio{min-height:27px}.form-horizontal .form-group{margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px}@media (min-width:768px){.form-horizontal .control-label{padding-top:7px;margin-bottom:0;text-align:right}}.form-horizontal .has-feedback .form-control-feedback{right:15px}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control newins" id="coll" placeholder="Collection">
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
<select id="len" class="form-control newins" >
<option value="">Length</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check this? @David Hope

Comment: Yes, I did. however for some reason the padding:12px; is not doing anything anymore! If you look at your inputs, they don't look same as my inputs!

Comment: you mean the text box height to be increased?

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant.

Comment: In .form-control you have `height:34px;` remove this and set your height as you want based on the tag

Comment: i have updated the answer.you can check now.Dont forget to accept this answer if helped you

Answer (score 0):

For having the same height just set `box-sizing: content-box;` in your `select` tag `style`. In order to have the same width you should use same size columns inside `div`es with `class="row"`.